# Java Servlet ResultSet to find out if table already exists

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, resultset

I wrote a little program that communicates with a MySQL database. The way it works is the user is on the index page where they enter a table name. The table name is passed to a servlet that displays what's in the table or tells the user that that table doesn't exist. I already wrote the code to display the table (if it exists) however I want to check if the table doesn't already exist and create that table. What some methods?

Comment: Welcome to SO. _What have you tried?_ Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] for tips on writing good SO questions.

Comment: My mistake. I searched SO and didn't see anything relating to my question so I posted it. I will look harder next time. Thank you for your timely responses.

Comment: I think what they want to see is the codes of what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can either run

```
show tables like "table_name";
```

or

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_schema = '[database name]' 
AND table_name = '[table name]';
```

which would return you a resultset similar to when you run SELECT query.